# Screen brightness too high on auto mode when in the dark room

Tags: screen, screen-brightness

An Android-based HTC Desire S is set to "auto brightness" display mode. The brightness is adjusted okay unless the device in a completely dark room. In a dark room then display is very bright - tolerable, but really uncomfortable.

Is there a way to make it less bright without disabling "auto brightness" mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to the market and search for screen filter. It Can get much dimmer than the brightness control by controlling the screen colors rather than just the backlight.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no.

Auto brightness is usually a battery waster.

I like to use the [Brightness](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.curvefish.widgets.brightnesslevel&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5jdXJ2ZWZpc2gud2lkZ2V0cy5icmlnaHRuZXNzbGV2ZWwiXQ..) widget, it will let you turn on/off auto-brightness or with one touch adjust the brightness to one of several presets.