# Lollipop Brightness too much

Tags: screen, 5.1-lollipop, screen-brightness

hey.

I am on running on a mediatek device and today did an upgrade to Lollipop 5.1 through flashing

Still exploring.

But one of the things I've noticed is that the brightness level is too much. Even in manual setting, I've set the bar to the lowest level, but still. Adaptive brightness seemingly works but only for a short while. Since, if I move to a Bright room/sphere,it brightens the screen.

Any work around?

Regards.

Comment: Is the device rooted? If not, use a screen filter. Also, have you tried turning off adaptive brightness in a bright room, setting the brightness to minimum and see whether it still feels too much?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Screen brightness too high on auto mode when in the dark room](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17431/screen-brightness-too-high-on-auto-mode-when-in-the-dark-room)

Answer (score 0):

Try lux on playstore, let me know

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vito.lux&hl=it